# Universal splitting algebra of a monic polynomial over a field is a field?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules, integral-extensions

The fourth paragraph of section 5 of F Richman's paper *Var Der Waerden's construction of a splitting field* claims that the universal splitting algebra of a monic polynomial over a field need not itself be a field.

I am confused by this. Firstly, the extension $A[s_1,\dots ,s_n]\subset A[x_1,\dots ,x_n]$ is integral (the $s_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials). Given a monic $f\in A[x]$, evaluating the above extension at the coefficients of $f$ gives the universal splitting algebra $A\to \mathrm{Split}_A(f)$, which is therefore also integral. But then, if $A$ is a field so must be the splitting algebra. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An integral extension of a field *which is a domain* must be a field.  But the universal splitting algebra may not even be a domain.  For instance, if $f$ is a quadratic then the universal splitting algebra will just be $A[x]/(f)$ (since once you have one root of $f$ the other is uniquely determined), which will only be a domain if $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Dear @Eric, I'm thinking that although the universal splitting algebra need not be a domain, the differences of the roots of $f$ are still cancellable in it. Is this false as well?

Comment: Yes, that is false.  The discriminant (which is some polynomial in the coefficients of $f$) will be equal to the product of all pairwise differences of the roots.  So, if the discriminant happens to be $0$, then at least one of those differences must not be cancellable.